# Make Foundation columns span multiple "rows" of columns

Tags: zurb-foundation

This could be an incredibly dumb question, but I'm at a loss on how to make 3 sets of columns line up with foundation's grid.

Here's the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dainovu3/qgc08k46/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: green;"></div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: blue;"></div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: red;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: yellow;"></div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: orange;"></div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: purple;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" style="height: 500px; background: black;"></div>
</div>
```

I want the black column to line up with the first "row" of columns **without** making the position of `.row` container relative and the `medium-3 columns` div absolute.

Furthermore, why doesn't this work like I assumed it would? Isn't a situation like this the whole point of a grid system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The right solution should be like this ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgc08k46/6/)):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: green;"></div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: blue;"></div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: red;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: yellow;"></div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: orange;"></div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: purple;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" style="height: 500px; background: black;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Do you happen to know what exactly putting the columns into rows is doing that allows the black column to fit nicely next to them? Inpsecting the elements doesn't appear to indicate anything different / would interfere with the column being there in the first place?

Comment: This is about how the Foundation's grid is built ([doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) - look into Advanced paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your fiddle is off is because each row needs to be 12 columns in length. If a row consists or more than 12 columns, the element that overflows then wraps to the next row, even if a row is not declared.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" style="height: 500px; background: black;"></div>
</div>
```

Your second div in the row makes these columns add up to 18 so it pushes it to the next level down. This is why last div of 3 columns appends to the end of your second div of 9 columns.

To get the layout you want, you'll need to have nested rows and ensure that each row adds up to 12 columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: green;"></div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: blue;"></div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: red;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">  
      <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: yellow;"></div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: orange;"></div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns" style="height: 250px; background: purple;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="medium-3 columns" style="height: 500px; background: black;"></div>
```